# What is wrong with this Unban command

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I tried to make an Unban command but when I try to unban someone by using the user's id, my bot just doesn't ban them and I don't know how to fix it.

The code:

```js
module.exports = {
    name: 'unban',
    description: 'unban a member',
    async execute(bot, message, args, cmd, Discord) {
      let userID = args[0]
      let reason = args.slice(1).join(" ")

      if(!reason) reason = 'Unspecified'
      if(!args[0]) return message.reply("Please enter the ID of the user you want to unban.")
      if(!message.member.hasPermission(['BAN_MEMBERS', 'ADMINISTRATOR'])) return message.reply("You don't have the right permission to do that.")

      message.guild.fetchBans().then(async bans => {
        if(bans.size == 0) return message.reply("There are no Bans on this server")
        let bUser = bans.find(b => b.user.id);
        if(!bUser) return message.reply("The mentioned ID is not banned")
        message.guild.members.unban(bUser)
        message.reply("User unbanned!")
      })
    }
  }
```

The error:

```
(node:11908) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error [BAN_RESOLVE_ID]: Couldn't resolve the user ID to unban.
at GuildMemberManager.unban (C:\Users\ADRIAN\Desktop\ZerOne BOT\node_modules\discord.js\src\managers\GuildMemberManager.js:243:36)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is `let bUser = bans.find(b => b.user.id)` returns the first user it finds in that collection because you don't check if the user id is the same, you only check if `b.user.id` exists on the banned user. It simply returns `true` on the first banned user.

You should check if `b.user.id === userID` instead:

```js
module.exports = {
    name: 'unban',
    description: 'unban a member',
    async execute(bot, message, args, cmd, Discord){
      let userID = args[0]
      let reason = args.slice(1).join(" ")

      if(!reason) reason = 'Unspecified'
      if(!userID) 
        return message.reply("Please enter the ID of the user you want to unban.")
      if(!message.member.hasPermission(['BAN_MEMBERS', 'ADMINISTRATOR'])) 
        return message.reply("You don't have the right permission to do that.")

      message.guild.fetchBans().then(async bans => {
        if(bans.size == 0) 
          return message.reply("There are no Bans on this server")

        let bUser = bans.find(banInfo => banInfo.user.id === userID);

        if(!bUser) 
          return message.reply("The mentioned ID is not banned")

        message.guild.members.unban(bUser.user.id)
        message.reply("User unbanned!")
      })
    }
  }
```

Comment: It still gives me the same error:
(node:9308) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error [BAN_RESOLVE_ID]: Couldn't resolve the user ID to unban.

Comment: Ah, yes, because `bUser` is not the user itself but the baninfo... It should be `.unban(bUser.user.id)`.